# Selenium WebDriverJs is unable to create a new client with iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium WebDriverJS with the iOS browser. Unfortunately this doesn't work as I need it to do.

I've set up the "iWebDriver"-Project like described at the [iPhoneDriver wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver). I've copied the python script and it worked. Even a small nodeJS project worked, but when I tried to run it from the Browser Firefox gives me the following Error message.

> Error: Unable to create a new client for this browser. The WebDriver session ID has not been defined.

The Code I'm trying to run:

```js
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer('http://localhost:3001/wd/hub').
    withCapabilities({'browserName': 'iPhone'}).
    build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');
driver.quit();
```

I've compiled webdriverjs like discribed at [the WebDriverJs wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs). And yes, webdriver.js is loaded ;)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the exact same error.

Comment: Unfortunetly it seems like webdriverJS (in browser, not node.js) is not able to create a new session by itself. Therefore you have to create a session manually fist and pass the session-id to webdriverJS at execution. I've edited webdriverJS to fit my needs. Take a look at [the comment in this listing](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#Controlling_the_Host_Browser) to see how to access an existing session. Basically they use the GET-Parameters "wdurl" (host-url) and "wdsid" (session-id). Hope this helps :)

Comment: Rats, this complicates things greatly, I am making a FF fox extension and for complicated reasons I need to control an IE browser with it. I was so excited when I saw the selenium could be controlled by JavaScript. But this has definitely taken the wind out of my sails.

Comment: With your mods to webdriverjs, did you code it up to create a new session?

Comment: I've simply created a new session outside of the webdriver-code. If you wan't to create a new session you might want to send a request to `/session` with the POST-Data `{"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"yourbrowser"}}` (maybe even more) and headers `{"Accept":"application/json; charset=utf-8"}}`. The response will be a redirect response to `yourselenium:port/someStuff/YOUR-SESSION-ID`. Depending on how you fire the request you will be redirected and get a JSON-Encoded Response or you will have to extract the session ID out of that redirect url ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like WebDriverJS is not capable of creating a new Session when not running in Node.js.

You have to create a Session manually and provide WebDriverJS with the session-id as the **wdsid** GET-Parameter (e.g. `urltowebdriver.html?wdsid=someID&wdurl=localhost:9000`).

Answer (score 2):

So I dug in and I think I have a solution. It seems like a hack but for firefox, and the firefox extension that I am making it works perfectly fine so far.

I edited the `webdriver.js` file's `webdriver.Builder.prototype.build` as so

```
webdriver.Builder.prototype.build = function() {
  var a;
//  if(webdriver.FirefoxDomExecutor.isAvailable()) {
//    return a = new webdriver.FirefoxDomExecutor, webdriver.WebDriver.createSession(a, this.getCapabilities())
//  }
  a = new webdriver.http.CorsClient(this.getServerUrl());
  a = new webdriver.http.Executor(a);
//  if(this.getSession()) {
//    return webdriver.WebDriver.attachToSession(a, this.getSession())
//  }
//  throw Error("Unable to create a new client for this browser. The WebDriver session ID has not been defined.");
  return webdriver.WebDriver.createSession(a, this.getCapabilities());
};
```

Basically I am forcing it to create a session, not sure why `FirefoxDomExecutor` was required since it works just fine on firefox and chrome with changes that I made.
Anyway thanks for getting me on the right track, and hopefully this will help others.

Comment: No need to monkey patch the code; just use this code directly in a local method.